# Angular 6 - Chained API calls not being fired

Tags: angular, api, typescript

I'm trying to create an authentication system, it works in 2 parts.

First I need to do call with the username and password, if this is valid it returns a code.

This code is used to check if it's valid, and if it is, the user i authenticated.

This call should gets the code:

```
  requestAuthCode(request: models.AuthenticationRequest): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(environment.auth.authorize, {
        headers: headers,
        params: params
      })
      .pipe(
        tap(val => this.authenticate(val.code)),
        catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
      );
  }
```

This call checks if a code is valid and authenticates the user

```
  authenticate(code: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<models.AuthenticationTokenResponse>(
        environment.auth.token,
        null,
        {
          headers: headers,
          params: params
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        tap(data => this.setSession(data)),
        catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
      );
  }
```

**The Goal**

If `requestAuthCode` gets a code in it's response, I want it to start the `authenticate` call, else it has to return an error.

However when I use

```
this.authService.requestAuthCode(request)
        .subscribe(
          data =>  {
            console.log(data);
          }
```

I just get the response data from my `requestAuthCode` and not from the chained `authenticate` call. I can also see that `authenticate` is not being triggerd.

How can I achieve that `requestAuthCode` triggers `authenticate` and returns that data to my component?

Comment: You never `.subscribe` to the observable, so the request isn't triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insteed of

```
  tap(val => this.authenticate(val.code)),
```

try

```
 switchMap(val => this.authenticate(val.code)),
```